# How do I convert Wordpress Categories and Tags into Woocommerce Categories and Tags?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have shop with 10 products, 10 Categories, and 10 Tags.
The eCommerce software I used were based on default Wordpress Posts, Categories, and Tags.

Now I want to convert my shop to Woocommerce.

I have no problem exporting the Posts into Woocommerce Products, but the  Categories and Tags do not follow this export. Instead, the new Products are uncategorized.

Is there a way to Transfer all my Categories and Tags directly over to Woocommerce?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to These steps which I do on my Site

1. remove woocommerce category base by this [plugin](https://premmerce.com/woocommerce-permalink-manager-remove-shop-product-product-category-url/) and test it by create any category .
2. remove the old wordpress category.
3. create the same category on woocommerce.

Comment: and if he has 100s of categories? Isn't there a better solution? a plugin or something?